# Trying to make a footer background (not an image) overflow a div to width of browser, but have no scrollbars

Tags: html, background, overflow

So on this site: http://istec.org
I am trying to have an aqua-colored background behind the footer that fits the width of the browser, but has no scrollbars.  The current solution I have used is:

```
.custom #footer-bg { /* wrapper for the footer */
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(0, 111, 111); 
}
.custom #footer-bg:before, .custom #footer-bg:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(0, 111, 111);  /* Matches the background of the footer's background */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1000px;
} 
.custom #footer-bg:before {
  right: 100%; 
}
.custom #footer-bg:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

...but this adds horizontal scrollbars.  Is there a way to get rid of the scrollbars, but make sure that they still appear if the browser size gets smaller than the content?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider putting a `footer` element below `div#page`, setting its width to 100% and giving it your background color, and nesting `div#footer` inside it with the same width as `div#page`. Set `margin: auto on`div#footer` to get it centered inside your footer.

Here's the markup:

```
<footer>
    <div id="footer">
        <!-- Your footer here -->
    </div>
</footer>
```

and the CSS:

```
footer { 
    width: 100%; 
    background: rgb(0, 111, 111);
}

#footer { 
    width: 102.9em; 
    margin: auto;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Even with these changes, you still have a tiny bit of horizontal scrolling, but it is not related to the footer. I can remove the footer, and the scrollbar is still there meaning one of your elements is wider than the page.